# Garbage collector stutters caused by downloading and uploading lots of data in python

Tags: python, networking, garbage-collection

Consider the code below

```
async with session.get("linktoimage.com") as resp:
  image = await resp.read()

async with session.post("targeturl.com", headers={"content-type": "application/octet-stream"}, data=image) as resp:
  ...
```

I am using aiohttp for both of these, and the web server this is running on does this a lot. After deploying this feature, we have noticed regular high latency spikes for its incoming requests. This is due to GC collects, because container memory drops rapidly at the same moment as the latency spikes.

I am not really sure how to go about optimizing this. I can always write a rust lib with python bindings to do this for me, that will also immediately deallocate the buffers and everything, but maybe there is an easier pythonic solution?

I was looking at `bytearray` and see if i could reuse the buffers, but the bytes themselves seem to be allocated as their own object anyway.

Thanks!

Comment: Python's reference implementation CPython has two GC mechanisms: Reference counting and testing if an object is reachable. Latter can be disabled with `gc.disable()`. If you do this and behavior is the same, the reference counting is the reason of the problem and there can't be done much. If instead memory increases further and further, there may be reference cycles which should be broken to reduce activity of the actual garbage collector.